# URL path pattern matching in spring interceptor

Tags: spring-mvc, interceptor

I want to exclude my static resources from my interceptor in spring mvc application.
I'm using exclude path like-

```
<mvc:exclude-mapping path="/resources/**.js"/>
```

But it doesn't work for the following path because there are `dots(.)` in the path:

```
/com-crud/resources/static/plugins/jquery/jquery.validate.min.js
```

What pattern should I use to match this path?

Comment: I hardly doubt this is the reason

Comment: I tried putting the whole URL instead of the pattern. and it works.

Comment: And how does that proof that `.` in name is the culprit? I would rather say `**.js` is invalid but cannot test that.

Comment: Yes. removing `.js` works. working pattern: `"/resources/**"` thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below if you want to specify the file type

```
<mvc:exclude-mapping path="/resources/**/*.js"/>
```

or just remove the file type as said in the comment

```
<mvc:exclude-mapping path="/resources/**"/>
```